# QGIS Hillshade not smooth enough

Tags: qgis, dem

I have been trying for a couple of days to get hillshading to work as I need it to but have run out of things to try and have tried the solutions I have found through searching the web.

I've created a TIFF and imported into QGIS and applied any number of combinations of hillshading settings but the result always ends up looking like the image on the left. The right handside shows the resolution and level of detail of my TIFF (tried 72dps upto 600dpi) and still the same. Is there a setting I am missing that will enable me to get a smoother gradient with my hill shading?

[image]

(I should add the 2 images are not showing the same area of the map, they are from the same map, just not the same area. It was a screen quick shot)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know more about your input data (GDALINFO output) and  exactly the steps you followed to get the two images

Comment: Have you created the dem from countour lines?

Comment: Yes, I took contour lines from the OS as vector and imported into illustrator using mapublisher.  I joined all the contour lines to make them individual shapes that I could colour. I then assigned a theme to each height of contour which was a percentage of black for each of the 29 contours. I then gave each a slight feather so the boundary between the shades was gradual. Exported as a geo TIFF and then added that layer to QGIS. Added hillshading and I get the terraced look seen in the sample.

Comment: It looks like your DEM has been made from the extrusion of the contour lines, that's why it has this terraced appearence.

Comment: I've added the contour lines on top so you can see where the original contours came from. I don't understand why it would terrace the TIFF i imported which has no record of them. The TIFF is just a greyscale image(isn't it?)..

Comment: The DEM is probably terraced aswell, you just dont see it as clearly. I think you need to apply some kind of smoothing to the DEM before hillshade.

Comment: You might want to consider acquiring. online DEM data for your project area, rather than mucking about with converting contours into a DEM. DEM data already exists for much of the earth's surface.  An internet search should suffice.

Comment: Stu, I tried that and there is data available but not as detailed as the contour data I have. It's for a map that covers an area of woodland around 50sq miles and for some reason, the detailed DEM data is missing for it. I've sorted the problem now to an acceptable level by using feather and blur in illustrator before adding layer to QGIS. The issue was definitely with my DEM data.